# ASPNET Core and async execution

Tags: async-await, asp.net-core

I'm still trying to get my head around how and when to use `async` methods in asp.net, and i could ask a dozen questions about it, but this behavior is surprising to me...from everything i've read if i create a an `async` method but declare it as a `void`, and then do not await it, it's essentially as if you just ran that async code on a worker thread without hanging around to get a result. that is, the void would return immediately to the caller, the caller would go about it's business, and potentially complete before the `async` method does. but in my .net core application, that is definitely not the case. i have an `async void` that i call from inside another async method and though i don't `await` it the threads blocks on the `async` code. what's happening here?

thanks.

Comment: Also i'm still playing with it - and now i can't get any `Task`s to run in the background, either?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm still trying to get my head around how and when to use async methods in asp.net

You'd use them when:

1. You have asynchronous work to do. Generally speaking, this means I/O-bound, not CPU-bound.
2. Your backend scales. E.g., it's a WebAPI, NoSQL service, SQL Server cluster, etc. If your backend is a single SQL Server instance, it's not scalable, and there's no point to using asynchrony on your web tier.

> it's essentially as if you just ran that async code on a worker thread

No. `async void` just prevents the caller from detecting when it's complete. It still runs in the same context as the caller, just like an `async Task` method would.

> the threads blocks on the async code

It's likely that your "async" code is actually synchronous. If it doesn't have an `await`, then the compiler will warn you that it's synchronous.

---

You may find my [intro to `async`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) blog post and [`async` on ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx) MSDN article helpful. As far as `async` goes, ASP.NET Core only changed a couple things: 1) There's no more ASP.NET request context, and 2) The entire pipeline is async-compatible, so things like async filters and async view components just work.

Comment: ok, that's great. i guess what's been throwing me off is that i read early on that "await" had nothing at all to do with threading, but as i see it that isn't so: you're clearly moving work off to another thread at some point if you're saying the current thread isn't blocking anymore while the awaitable is executing. that is, the awaitable is executing in some thread, and not the one it was called from. so i guess some threads are more valuable than others, so to speak? as that the point of this, really?

Comment: @user2403744: No; for truly asynchronous code, [there is no thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Comment: grrr, ok. i'll go down the rabbit hole this evening and convince myself of what i already know to to be true: you're right. it's going to make my brain hurt, i just know it.

Comment: Hi @StephenCleary what do you mean by "I/O-bound" in 1.)? High traffic / lots of users ?thanks for clarifying

Comment: @gsharp: [I mean an operation that spends most of its time doing input or output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/O_bound). Doesn't have anything to do with high traffic or lots of users, but rather what the operation is doing (e.g., sending an HTTP request to a REST API is I/O-bound; calculating pi is CPU-bound).